# Multi Checked on checkbox from MySQL data which is separated by Comma (,)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox, explode

There is Update form so I need that, if some checkbox input have already checked according to MySQL data then It will show checked.

```
<?php 
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT leavingEquipment FROM orderform WHERE orderNo='$orderNo'");  // here are the checked data 
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($result as $row4){
        $leavingEquipment = explode(", ",$row4['leavingEquipment']); // Here I use explode I check this with var_dump 
        $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM equipment"); // here all equipment 
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach($result as $row3) {
                $leavingEquipment3=$row3['equipmentTitle'];
                ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="leavingEquipment[]" value="<?php echo $row3['equipmentTitle']; ?>" <?php if($leavingEquipment==$leavingEquipment3) echo 'checked'; ?>><label class="control-label"><?php echo $row3['equipmentTitle']; ?></label>
                <?php
             }
    }
?>
```

Var_dum output like this:
array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "Bluetooth" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb2dz.jpg)=> string(6) "casing" }

It shows like this:[image]

But I need like this:
[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here,

```
<input ... name="leavingEquipment[]" } value="<?php echo $row3['equipmentTitle']; ?>" <?php if($leavingEquipment==$leavingEquipment3) echo 'checked'; ?>> ...
                                     ^ a lone closing bracket                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You're comparing an array `$leavingEquipment` with a string `$leavingEquipment3`.

Instead use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function to check whether a checkbox is already checked or not i.e an equipment is already in the array or not. So your inner `foreach` loop should be like this:

```
// your code

foreach($result as $row3) {
    $leavingEquipment3=$row3['equipmentTitle'];
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="leavingEquipment[]" value="<?php echo $row3['equipmentTitle']; ?>" <?php if(in_array($leavingEquipment3, $leavingEquipment)){ echo " checked='checked'"; } ?>>
    <label class="control-label"><?php echo $row3['equipmentTitle']; ?></label>
    <?php
}

// your code
```

Comment: long closing bracket was by mistake.

Comment: @AmranurRahman Please *accept* the answer to close the question. Also, you should get into the habit of *accepting* the answers, it'll encourage other developers to help you further. Right now, it seems like all your questions are on free floating *open* state. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)